# How to Apply CSS to element added by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my application I am applying some CSS onload and then appending some html using Jquery! My problem is that CSS is not being applied to the newly added element. How can i make sure that the CSS is applied to newly appended html?

Please have a look at  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MfSga/)

HTML:

```
<body onload="loaded()">
<div id="a">
    <div class="main">a</div>
    <div class="main">b</div>
    <div class="main">c</div>
    <div class="main">d</div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="click Me" onclick="clickMe()" />
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function loaded() {
    var posts = $('.main'),
    postCount = posts.length,
    postHalf = Math.round(postCount / 2),
    wrapHTML = '<div class="tab"></div>';
    posts.slice(0, postHalf).wrapAll(wrapHTML);
    posts.slice(postHalf, postCount).wrapAll(wrapHTML);
}

function clickMe() {
  $("#a").append("<div class='main'>e</div>");
}
```

CSS:

```
.tab {
    width: 10%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Check markup in developer tools you'll see what's going on.

Comment: what css rule are u talking abt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your newly added element has class `.main`, and in css you have `.tab`, so no css will be applied to your new element obviously.

IF I understand correctly what you want to achieve, I'd say you need to re-run loaded() function once new element is added. So new div is wrapped in `.tab` div, just like it happens onload for existing elements.

But you will need to unwrap elements before you call loaded() function, otherwise some weird things will happen. Like so:

```
function loaded() {
    var posts = $('.main'),
        postCount = posts.length,
        postHalf = Math.round(postCount / 2),
        wrapHTML = '<div class="tab"></div>';
    posts.slice(0, postHalf).wrapAll(wrapHTML);
    posts.slice(postHalf, postCount).wrapAll(wrapHTML);
}

function clickMe() {
  $('.main').unwrap();
  $("#a").append("<div class='main'>e</div>");
  loaded();
}
```

THIS should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/MfSga/6/

Besides, don't use onload onclick inside html. Do it in js file.

Comment: Thanks @Sandro-Dzneladze It worked! I am not aware of `unwrap()`